# Can I change from standard service to priority service after application? UK

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

I've submitted by T5 temporary worker (GAE) visa extension application using the standard service. Is there any way I can change this to the priority service? When I was applying, the website said you couldn't. But my sponsor has indicated they would pay the extra £500 for the priority service if we could switch to it. (And how do I do this?)